# How to i change the date time format on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-analysis, datetime-format, errorformat

I am working on a datasheet on Google sheets and I am trying to change values in column (D) to date time format, so I went to Format<number<date time. But only a few values are getting converted and the rest remain the same. Please see below-

Screenshot of column D

[image: 1]

The values aligned on right are converted and the left ones aren't. I even tried paint format, trim white spaces but it didnt work. Please suggest a way on how to resolve this error. Also, there are 49623 values in column D.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2):

Your spreadsheet is set to a locale that uses the `mm/dd/yyyy` date format, while your data is using the `dd/mm/yyyy` date format. That means that the dates where the day of the month is less than or equal to `12` will get converted to dates incorrectly, and the rest of the data will remain as text strings.

To make it work, choose **File > Settings > Locale** and choose a locale that matches your data, then repaste the data to convert it correctly.

The "49623 values" are dateserials that can be converted to dates by formatting them in a date format. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.